# Formatting long Relational Algebraic expressions

Tags: amsmath, line-breaking

I have the following in LaTeX

```
\begin{multline*}
\Pi_{SNAME}(\sigma_{(COLOUR = 'SCREW' \wedge STATUS > 20 \wedge SUPPLIERNUM = SNUM \wedge PARTNUM = PNUM)}\\ ((\rho (SNUM, SUPPLIERNUM) (SUPPLIER)) \times (\rho (PNUM, PARTNUM (PART)) \times (SUPPLY)))
\end{multline*}
```

[image]

I cannot seem to add `\\` at certain points (like halfway through the selection condition). Any advice for a way to break this up more readably?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\substack` (from `amsmath` package that you are already using) to make multi-line subscripts.  Note also you should not set mult-letter identifiers using the default math italic, the font is designed to make adjacent letters look not like a word but like a product of single letter variables. I use `\mathrm` here but you could use `\mathit`.  This is still not very readable it may need splitting up more.

[image]

or with more line breeaks (but still unreadably ugly)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}
\Pi_{\substack{
\operatorname{SNAME}
(\sigma_{\substack{(\mathrm{COLOUR} = '\mathrm{SCREW}' \wedge\\
 \mathrm{STATUS} > 20 \wedge\\
 \mathrm{SUPPLIERNUM} = \mathrm{SNUM} \wedge\\
 \mathrm{PARTNUM} = \mathrm{PNUM})}}\hfill\\
((\rho (\mathrm{SNUM}, \mathrm{SUPPLIERNUM}) (\mathrm{SUPPLIER})) \times\\
 (\rho (\mathrm{PNUM}, \mathrm{PARTNUM} (\mathrm{PART})) \times (\mathrm{SUPPLY}))))}}
\end{multline*}


\end{document}
```

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}
\Pi_{
\substack{
\operatorname{SNAME}
(\sigma_{(\mathrm{COLOUR} = '\mathrm{SCREW}' \wedge \mathrm{STATUS} > 20 \wedge \mathrm{SUPPLIERNUM} = \mathrm{SNUM} \wedge \mathrm{PARTNUM} = \mathrm{PNUM})}\hfill\\
((\rho (\mathrm{SNUM}, \mathrm{SUPPLIERNUM}) (\mathrm{SUPPLIER})) \times (\rho (\mathrm{PNUM}, \mathrm{PARTNUM} (\mathrm{PART})) \times (\mathrm{SUPPLY}))))}}
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for the tip about italics - I'll bear that in mind for future. Unfortunately, the output I'm getting using subscript is perhaps a little less readable than before (and of course, I'm sadly still unable to break up the selection condition)

Comment: @jwaterson as I say you can use `\substack` to allow breaking where exactly do you want more breaks? you could use another substack in the subscript to `\sigma`

Comment: @jwaterson oh actually I think I misread your nesting and you only want substack on the sigma, I'll adjust

Comment: Ah right, I see yes, ```\substack``` does allow me to do what I asked for (greater flexibility with line breaks), so I've accepted your answer. I think unfortunately though, the expression is destined to be forever ugly...